Dynamically alias selected columns in Clickhouse
I have a table like



room
id
f1
f2
...
f500




A
1001
...
...
...
...


A
....
...
...
...
...


A
9999
...
...
...
...


B
1001
...
...
...
...


B
....
...
...
...
...


B
9999
...
...
...
...



I want to pivot the table on room name. When query like
SELECT id, COLUMNS(f*) FROM mytable WHERE room = 'A'

how can the selected column aliases be prefixed with room name in a batch like room_A_f1, room_A_f2, ..., room_A_f500?
This article provides a way to pivot the table, but it requires to manually specify column aliases. In my case there are too many columns so infeasible to do that.
Edit:
Another way is to use the prefixed table names of joins, but not perfect:
WITH room_A AS (
    SELECT id, COLUMNS(f*) FROM mytable WHERE room = 'A'
),
room_B AS (
    SELECT id, COLUMNS(f*) FROM mytable WHERE room = 'B'
)
SELECT *
FROM room_A INNER JOIN room_B USING id;

The returned table will have columns lik id, f1, f2, ..., f500, room_B.f1, room_B.f2, ..., room_B.f500. So room_A columns don't have the prefix. Is there a way to keep table name prefix for room_A too?

I don't use ClickHouse, but I don't know any way to do this in any implementation of SQL. The expressions and aliases in the select-list must be fixed before the query begins reading data. So there's no way for a query to read data and dynamically add more columns as it reads the distinct data values. The solution is to do two queries. One to discover the distinct values, then write some code to format a second query with the pivoted columns, one for each data value. You don't have to type them all — you write code to do that for you.
